# reindex to match original columns

Tags: pandas

I have the training data (**df**) that looks like this...

```
from io  import StringIO
import pandas as pd

myst="""india, 905034 , 19:44   
USA, 905094  , 19:33
Russia,  905154 ,   21:56

"""
u_cols=['country', 'index', 'current_tm']

myf = StringIO(myst)
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(myst), sep=',', names = u_cols)
```

I got the test data (**df1**), but the columns do not match with the original training set.

```
myst1="""india, 123455 , 19:44   
USA, 233455  , 19:33
Russia,  5666432 ,   21:56

"""
u_cols1=['country', 'index', 'dummy_col']
df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(myst1), sep=',', names = u_cols1)
```

Is it possible to reindex the new data to match with the original strcture so that the final dataframe will look like this (**df2**)?

```
myst2="""india, 123455 , NULL   
USA, 233455  , NULL
Russia,  5666432 ,   NULL

"""
u_cols2=['country', 'index', 'current_tm']
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(myst2), sep=',', names = u_cols2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with training data columns:

```
df3 = df1.reindex(columns=df.columns)
print (df3)
  country    index  current_tm
0   india   123455         NaN
1     USA   233455         NaN
2  Russia  5666432         NaN
```